# How to detect a tap on header of currently selected PivotItem

Tags: c#, xaml, events, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have  a `Pivot` control. I want a special behavior -- everytime the user taps the header of currently chosen `PivotItem`, I want to react to that. However, this reaction can not happen when the tapped header does not belong to the currently selected pivot item.

My plan was as follows:

For each `PivotItem` create a custom header and associate its tap event with a handler:

```
<phone:PivotItem DataContext="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}" Content="{Binding}" x:Name="itemA">
    <phone:PivotItem.Header>
        <TextBlock x:Name="headerA" Text="A" Tap = "HeaderA_Tapped"/>
    </phone:PivotItem.Header>
</phone:PivotItem>
```

And in the handler, test whether the tapped item is currently selected, if yes, react:

```
protected void HeaderA_Tapped(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    if (mainPivot.SelectedItem.Equals(itemA))
    {
        //selected item is the same pivotItem that reported tapping event
        react();
    }
}
```

It seemed pretty straightforward, but after giving it a try I found out that the tap event was reported only AFTER the selection changed event. In cases, where the user taps currently not selected pivotItem header, the pivot will change the selection accordingly (default behavior that I want to keep), and only then it reports the tap event. However, that is too late for my code, because in that moment the tapped header and currently selected item are already the same.

Is there any way how I can detect whether the tap initiated a selection change? Or is there a way to revert the order of events? I guess currently the WP event model sinks the event from the root of Visual Tree down to leafs -> therefore the `Pivot` gets to handle it sooner, and only then it gets to header `TextBlock`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so after some read of my *Windows Phone 8 Development Internals* book by Andrew Whitechapel and Sean McKenna (do not ask why I did not do it sooner) I got a working solution.

I am not going into full fledged detailed discussion of events, just to point out conclusions relevant to my issue. It seems that in the WP8 event model there are at least two types of events, lower level routed events and logical touch gesture events. The routed events are routed through visual tree from the most concrete element (in my case the header `TextBlock` control) to the root (therefore `Pivot` should have get it later). Logical events are not routed, they appear only on a single element (e.g., my `TextBlock` control), and therefore their handlers have to be registered on the particular element. I assume that the logical events are raised by the element based on the lower level routed event. Applied to my case, it seems that first the lower-level `MouseLeftButtonDown` (or button up) event was raised, routed to `Pivot` that used it to change selection, and only then my `TextBlock` control created the logical `Tap` event. This would result in behavior that I observed on my emulator. I am not sure about the way how the routed events are really routed and how the logical events are created, so if I made a mistake in my conclusions, please correct me. However, I was able to solve my problem.

Using aforementioned assumptions I decided to listen to lower-level routed events instead of logical tap gesture. Using this `MouseLeftButtonUp` event I was notified before the new `PivotItem` was selected, thus giving me chance to check whether the raised `MouseLeftButtonUp` was originated by currently selected `PivotItem`.

And so finally the solution:

My XAML `Pivot` definition (notice that now I am handling `MouseLeftButtonUp` events on the `TextBlock` controls, instead of logical `Tap` events):

```
<phone:Pivot Title="Pivot" Name="mainPivot">
    <phone:PivotItem DataContext="{Binding A}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}" Content="{Binding A}">
        <phone:PivotItem.Header>
             <TextBlock Text="A" MouseLeftButtonUp="HeaderHandlerA"/>
        </phone:PivotItem.Header>
    </phone:PivotItem>

    <phone:PivotItem DataContext="{Binding B}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}" Content="{Binding B}">
        <phone:PivotItem.Header>
             <TextBlock Text="B" MouseLeftButtonUp="HeaderHandlerB"/>
        </phone:PivotItem.Header>
    </phone:PivotItem>
</phone:Pivot>
```

Since I have a different handler for each `PivotItem` header, I can simply test selected index with a constant. The corresponding handlers in the code-behind:

```
private void HeaderHandlerA(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // HeaderHandlerA is allways called within the first PivotItem,
    // therefore I can just test whether selected index is 0 (index of the first PivotItem)
    if (mainPivot.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        OnSelectedItemTapped();
    }
    // else the "tapped" header was not the selected one and I do nothing
}

private void HeaderHandlerB(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (mainPivot.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        OnSelectedItemTapped();
    }
}
```

Maybe not the most elegant solution, but it works...

Answer (score 1):

I think you should track Pivot SelectedIndex and update SelectedIndex in Selection_Changed event by using a Timer.
Some think like this:

```
int selectedIndex;
func Selection_ChangedEvent()
{
    //use a timer to update selectedIndex
    //something like: Timer.do(selectedIndex = Pivot.SelectedIndex, 100)
    //fire after a specify time. adjust this for the best result. 
}
```

And in your tapped event

```
HeaderA_Tapped()
{
    if(selectedIndex == "index of item A in Pivot")
    {
        react();
    }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about a timer too, but it seems really like hacking than a solution + I am expecting the user to fast scroll through pivot items, so to be honest I am a little worried that this 'solution' could pose some concurrency issues (e.g., the user changes selection and fast after that clicks on new selected item, but the timer did not update the selection yet, etc.).. I am leaving this option as my last resolution, if I won't find a better option.

Answer (score 0):

Create Pivot selection changed event

```
<phone:Pivot Title="MY APPLICATION" x:Name="MainPivot" SelectionChanged="Pivot_SelectionChanged">
```

Add the event handlers to **cs** file

```
private void Pivot_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (MainPivot.SelectedIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            // do something
            break;
        case 1:
            //do something
            break;
    }
}
```

For more details see this search
https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=Y1XdVZruLqfG8AfUuquIAQ&gws_rd=ssl#q=wp8+c%23+pivot+selectionchanged

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windowsapps/en-US/1baf74fa-0ddd-4226-a02d-a7fc9f80374d/pivot-static-header-like-twitter-app

Comment: this solution listens to selection changed event. That is exactly the event I do NOT want nor need. I need the tap event on header in case when selection does NOT change.